# How do I animate my radial gradient to bounce?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have been trying to add a moving animation to the canvas on my page of a newly generated bouncing ball using JavaScript.
While I have been able to successfully generate the ball on canvas, getting it to actually move has been a challenge.
I suspect that I have improperly arranged the code and that I am using a layout that while valid is simply not executing all of the code. I am using a radial gradient instead of either the more common and easier to use simple circles or premade .PNG pictures simply because it looks better than a plain circle and offers more of a flexible foundation for future work and learning than using a image like ball.png.

My HTML file side code is as follows:

```
<canvas id="ballCanvas" width="1000" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script src="ballAnimation.js"></script>
```

Nice and simple.

The JavaScript is in a separate file from the actual HTML and is as follows:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("ballCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let raf;


const ball = {
 vx: 5,
 vy: 2,
 x: 100,
 y: 100,
 draw() {

// Create a radial gradient
// The inner circle is at x=250, y=90, with radius=30
// The outer circle is at x=240, y=100, with radius=70
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(250, 90, 30, 240, 100, 70);
 
// Add three color stops
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(155, 0, 5, 0.8 )");
gradient.addColorStop(0.9, "rgba(50, 0, 5, 0.5 )");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(145, 150, 150, 1 )");

// Set the fill style and draw a rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
 },
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;

 if (ball.y + ball.vy > canvas.height || ball.y + ball.vy < 0) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.vx > canvas.width || ball.x + ball.vx < 0) {
    ball.vx = -ball.vx;
  }

  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
});

ball.draw();
```

The code I am using was originally derived from this:

```
type here
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let raf;

const ball = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  vx: 5,
  vy: 2,
  radius: 25,
  color: "blue",
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
  },
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;
  ball.vy *= 0.99;
  ball.vy += 0.25;

  if (ball.y + ball.vy > canvas.height || ball.y + ball.vy < 0) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.vx > canvas.width || ball.x + ball.vx < 0) {
    ball.vx = -ball.vx;
  }

  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
});

ball.draw();
```

Original source and tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Advanced_animations

I have checked the code using a validator and could not find any errors. A previous attempt wouldn't render at all due to an invalid layout, but I was able to fix that after running the code through an IDE debugger and online code validator resulting in the current code.

I am doing this so that I can learn how to add more complex animations to my web pages in the future while having them look good and not have to be preprepared images like "ball.png".
While my tests show that I can animate a CSS3 radial gradient they sadly do not look right and do not provide as much of a foundation for some of my work.

I am currently trying to see if I can find some tool that will let me better see what the code is doing when I run it. My goal is to generate at will a custom radial gradient and then have it bounce around the canvas. Once I have such a tool and/or sufficiently good advice, or am sure I can not quickly find either, I am going to return to spending hours looking at and rearranging the layout to see if I can find another valid one that fully functions.

Comment: I have now partially solved the problem by readding the radius value and by adding a customized bit of the original code as follows: Line 1:draw() {
       Line 2:  ctx.beginPath();
         Line 3: ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
Line 4:  ctx.closePath();
Line 5:  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
 Line 6: ctx.fill(); Unfortunately this produces merely a solid colour albeit colour changing ball that splits off from the original image and acts like part of a different layer of the animation.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).